# How to rewrite a C# foreach in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

When I build the following, I get the error `Cannot modify members of 'pd' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'`.

```
foreach (var w in tt.Weeks)
  foreach (var d in w.Days)
    foreach (var pd in d.Periods)
      if (pd.Type == TimetablePeriod.Types.Registration) pd.ClassId = clsId;
```

I understand why this error occurs, but I'm trying to think of a neat way to rewrite the code. I could use nested `for` loops, but is there a nice LINQ solution?

(In case it's not clear, I'm trying to set the `ClassId` of all periods in all days of all weeks to `clsId`, wherever the `PeriodType` is `TimetablePeriod.Types.Registration`.)

Comment: Is `pd` a mutable struct? With a class this code should compile.

Comment: It's a struct, but ClassId has a public setter so surely it would be okay?

Comment: You'll need to use `for`. Or replace your struct by a class.

Comment: Thanks. I've never really understood the difference between a struct and a class. Something about value and reference types I think? Any disadvantages of changing to a class?

Comment: CodeInChaos please submit your comment as an answer so I can upvote =)

Comment: Mutable classes have reference sematics. Structs have value semantics(i.e. they are copied all the time), but mutable structs should be avoided unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Strong suggestion: If you're uncertain about the difference between value and reference types, steer well away from using `struct`. Stick with `class` until you've got more experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have a `struct` like this:

```
public struct Period
{
    public SomeType ClassId{get;set;}
}
```

This means that any iteration over a collection using either LINQ or `foreach` will work on copies of the values. So if you modify them you only modify a temporary copy which will then be discarded. The original struct will remain untouched.

For this and many other reasons mutable structs should be avoided unless you have a really good reason to use them. (Search for "Mutable structs evil" and you'll find a lot)

In your case you can simply replace `struct` with class. You then get reference semantics.

Or you can use a for loop, which gives you direct access. But it will still not compile with the naive implementation:

```
for(int i=i;i<list.Count;i++)
  list[i].ClassId=something;
```

Because the indexer on lists is a property, which copies its results. With arrays this would work since the indexer of an array returns a managed reference(or something similar). For lists you need to do:

```
for(int i=i;i<list.Count;i++)
{
  var copy=list[i];
  copy.ClassId=something;
  list[i]=copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code.

Your problem is not related to whether the code is LINQ or not as @CodeInChaos mentioned. As `pd` is Struct type, you need to replace it to set the value(clsId).

```
foreach (var w in tt.Weeks)
{
    foreach (var d in w.Days)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < d.Periods.Count; i++)
        {
            if (d.Periods[i].Type == TimetablePeriod.Types.Registration)
                d.Periods[i] = new Period(clsId, ....);
        }
    }
}
```